# Regex dependency from previous match

Tags: c#, regex

I am reading up on regular expressions and I am trying to make an expression which will match a date in the format date/month/year.

The expression will have a some but not much validation. E.g `04/17/2012` is not a valid date as there is no 17th month.

I am making the expression so that the separators can be both `/`, `.`, `-` and `.` but now I would like it to be the same separator between the components. Is there a way to adjust the regular expression so that if it matches the separator `/` (or any other) between the date and month then it will only match the `/` separator (or the one it previous matched)  between the month and year?

This is my expression as it is now:

```
(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]|[1-9])(/|\.( |)|-)(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9])(/|\.( |)|-)([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})
```

I will be using the expression in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backreference `\2` can solve your issue:

```
^(19|20)\d\d([- /.])(0[1-9]|1[012])\2(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

Read this [article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
([0-2]\d|30|31)(/.-)(0\d|1[0-2])\2\d{4}
```

Use back reference \2 and prefer \d to [0-9]

Answer (score 0):

Use a backreference (`\1`) in your search pattern, something like (syntax untested)

```
\d+([-./])\d+\1\d+
```

Or more verbosely (Python)

```
>>> pat = re.compile(r"""
... \d{2}          # day
... ([-./])        # separator
... \d{2}
... \1             # repeat of first separator
... \d{4}          # year
... """, re.VERBOSE )
>>> mystr
'The date is 17/04/2012'
>>> result = pat.search(mystr)
>>> result.group()
'17/04/2012'
```

Then the `\1` should match whichever of `[-./]` was obtained for the first separator.

If you actually want to do this for production purposes, you are almost always better off locating the date using a general pattern, then parsing it using a proper date parsing module.  This is because dates have a lot of edge cases that are hard to code into a regex. (Quick: write me a regex that correctly allows 29/02/2000, but disallows 29/02/2001!)